# Show that the function $g: S \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, given by $z\mapsto z^3$, is surjective but not injective.

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Let $S$ denote the closed sector $0 \leq \arg (z) \leq 2\pi/3$, in the complex plane, including the vertex at $z = 0$. Show that the function, $g: S \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ , given by $z\mapsto z^3$, is surjective but not injective.

Another exam prep question.

Since we are given the argument sector, is the best way to evaluate this using Polar form? 
$z = r \mathrm{cis}(-)$ (data)

so $r^3 \mathrm{cis} (0) \leq z^3 \leq r^3 \mathrm{cis} (2\pi)$

So I guess this shows that the function is surjective. But how do I go about showing it is not injective?

Many thanks!

Comment: What do the inequalities in  "r^3 cis (0) <= z^3 <= r^3 cis (2Pi)" mean?  You did not show that the function is surjective.  Do you know how to use polar form to find roots?

Comment: I guess what I was getting at is that z^3 can take any argument between 0 degrees and 360 degrees, so the range is surjective. All complex numbers can be covered? Yes, I know the formula for finding roots of complex numbers in polar form. How would I use that here? Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: To show a map $f:A\to B$ is surjective means to show that for all $b\in B$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$.  So suppose that $w$ is a complex number.  Can you find $z\in S$ such that $z^3=w$?

Comment: ok, so z = w^(1/3). Let w = r cis (theta) (sorry I don't know how to do the symbols here). the z = w^(1/3) = r^(1/3) cis ((Theta + 2pi*k)/3) where k = 0,1,2. How would I proceed from here?

Comment: You have to show that you can always choose $k$ so that $z$ is in $S$.  (To do the symbols here, you put them between dollar signs and use LaTeX.  E.g., $r^{1/3}(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$ is written as `$r^{1/3}(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$`.  $\mathrm{cis}(\theta)$ can be written as `$\mathrm{cis}(\theta)$`.  See the answers [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto) for suggestions on how to get used to LaTeX.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute $g(r e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{3}})$ and $g(r)$. What do you notice?

Comment: Yes, they give the same point in the codomain. Thanks!

Comment: Hence not injective...